# Ruby price calculator for groceries

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, ruby

I am good at logic and most of the time I write working code. But I want to learn writing code which follows best practices and is very efficient. I tried to implement some of them in my code but it still looks very unclean.
Could anyone please explain how I can make this code better and make it production standard code.

This is my ruby code:

````
class Items
  @@items = {}
  def initialize(name, price)
    @@items[name] = price
  end

  def self.all
    @@items
  end
end

class SaleItems
  @@sale_items = {}
  def initialize(name, units, price)
    @@sale_items[name] = { 'units' => units, 'price' => price}
  end

  def self.all
    @@sale_items
  end
end

class PriceCalculator

  def start_billing
    input = get_input
    @purchased_items = input.split(',').map(&:strip)
    if !@purchased_items.empty?
      quantity = count_items 
      price = calculate_bill(quantity)
      billing_items = quantity.each_with_object(price) { |(k,v), billing_items| 
        billing_items[k] = {'units' => v, 'price' => price[k]} 
      }
      display_bill(billing_items, quantity)
    else
      puts "Sorry! no items were given to process the bill"
    end
  end

  private

    def get_input
      puts "Please enter all the items purchased separated by a comma"
      input = gets.chomp
    end

    def count_items
      @purchased_items.inject(Hash.new(0)){ |quantity, item|
          quantity[item] += 1
          quantity
      }
    end

    def calculate_bill quantity
      price = {}
      quantity.each { |item,value| 
        if SaleItems.all[item].nil? 
          price[item] = quantity[item]*Items.all[item]
        else   
          price[item] = (((quantity[item]/SaleItems.all[item]['units']).floor)*SaleItems.all[item]['price']) + ((quantity[item]%SaleItems.all[item]['units'])*Items.all[item])
        end 
        }
        price
    end

    def display_bill billing_items, quantity
      total_price = billing_items.inject(0){ |tot, (item,v)|
        tot + v['price']
      }

      actual_price = quantity.inject(0){ |tot, (item,units)| 
        tot + (units * Items.all[item])
      }

      puts "Item          Quantity          Price"
      puts "------------------------------------------"

      billing_items.each{ |item, v|
        puts "#{item.ljust(20)} #{v['units']}           $#{v['price']}"
      }
      puts "Total price : #{total_price.round(3)}"
      puts "You saved #{(actual_price - total_price).round(3)} today."
    end

end

begin
  # creating inventory of items
  Items.new('milk', 3.97)
  Items.new('bread', 2.17)
  Items.new('banana', 0.99)
  Items.new('apple', 0.89)

  # creating sale items
  SaleItems.new('milk',2,5.00)
  SaleItems.new('bread',3,6.00)

  pc = PriceCalculator.new
  puts pc.start_billing
end
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Rubocop Report

There is a nice topic on [Class vs Instance variables](https://mixandgo.com/learn/how-to-avoid-the-ruby-class-variable-problem) online. Are you sure you would like to use class variables in classes `Items` and `SalesItems`?

> ```
> class Items
>   @@items = {}
>   ..
> ```

```
class Items
  @items = {}
  ..
```

Class `PriceCalculator` has a couple of issues that need to be addressed.

> ```
> billing_items = quantity.each_with_object(price) { |(k,v), billing_items|
> ```

`billing_items` inside the `each_with_object` hides the member from the outer scope. To avoid confusion which variable is accessed, consider changing the name of the variable inside the inner call.

> ```
> def get_input
> ```

Ruby guidelines don't like these java-style accessors. However, since the method isn't actually an accessor, it is acceptable ([Clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097084/why-does-rubocop-or-the-ruby-style-guide-prefer-not-to-use-get-or-set)).

> ```
> price[item] = (((quantity[item]/SaleItems.all[item]['units']).floor)*SaleItems.all[item]['price']) + ((quantity[item]%SaleItems.all[item]['units'])*Items.all[item])
> ```

Try to keep the length of your lines below 80 characters. Ruby is meant to read vertically.

Other:

- Method `start_billing` might have many lines. Consider splitting up methods if they take more than 10 lines. Ruby likes short methods.
- The [complexity](https://codeclimate.com/blog/deciphering-ruby-code-metrics/) of method `calculate_bill` is too high. Consider splitting up its content into multiple methods, each doing their specific part.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @dfhwze has said, I wanted to give some suggestions on general ruby best practice and readibility:

### Multiline Blocks

In `PriceCalculator#start_billing`, `PriceCalculator#count_items` and in a couple other methods you use muliline blocks like so:

```
foobar.each { |*args|
  # do stuff
  # more stuff
}
```

The use of `{}` is really only intended for single line blocks -- when you have more than one line inside of the block, it's best to use `do ... end`. This will make your code a bit easier to read. From my example:

```
foobar.each do |*args|
  # do stuff
  # more stuff
end
```

### Method Definitions

In ruby, while it's valid syntax to define methods like `def some_method argument`, it's really easy to misread that as `def some_method_argument`, and so it's considered better practice to put parentheses around your method definitions, like so: `def some_method(argument)`.

### Other

I just wanted to take a look at this method:

```
def calculate_bill quantity
  price = {}
  quantity.each { |item,value| 
    if SaleItems.all[item].nil? 
      price[item] = quantity[item]*Items.all[item]
    else   
      price[item] = (((quantity[item]/SaleItems.all[item]['units']).floor)*SaleItems.all[item]['price']) + ((quantity[item]%SaleItems.all[item]['units'])*Items.all[item])
    end 
    }
    price
end
```

Specifically, in the if statement, you could take advantage of a common ruby idiom for generating hashes, and instead of generating a `price` hash just return the hash you want:

```
def calculate_bill quantity
  quantity.map { |item,value| [item, SalesItems.all[item].nil? ? quantity[item]*Items.all[item] : (((quantity[item]/SaleItems.all[item]['units']).floor)*SaleItems.all[item]['price']) + ((quantity[item]%SaleItems.all[item]['units'])*Items.all[item])] }.to_h
end
```

(note how I used the `{}` for a one line block). If you wanted to expand this to make it a bit more readable:

```
def calculate_bill quantity
  quantity.map do |item,value|
    v = if SalesItems.all[item].nil?
      quantity[item]*Items.all[item]
    else
      (((quantity[item]/SaleItems.all[item]['units']).floor)*SaleItems.all[item]['price']) + ((quantity[item]%SaleItems.all[item]['units'])*Items.all[item])
    end
    [item, v]
  end.to_h
end
```

I'd also recommend breaking up that massive formula into some smaller pieces with better variable names to make it easier to tweak it later if you need to.